# how do I create a xml namespace for local use?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

is it possible to create a xmlns with out my own domain(I'm running the http server locally and an oracle database) if not please suggest alternatives

this is in my xml file

```
 <ModelList xmlns="http://www.onenetwork.com/Platform" xmlns:vc="http://www.onenetwork.com/Platform">
  <ValueChainId>1217</ValueChainId>
  <CustomModelName>Standard ZGMP.Place</CustomModelName>
  <ActionName>ZGMP.Create</ActionName>
  <Place xmlns="http://www.onenetwork.com/Platform/places">
    <ValueChainId>1217</ValueChainId>
    <PlaceName>Home</PlaceName>
    <Address>
      <vc:Country>RSA</vc:Country>
      <vc:Component Type="STREET1">98 Elm Road</vc:Component>
      <vc:Component Type="CITY">Benoni</vc:Component>
      <vc:Component Type="PROVINCE">Gauteng</vc:Component>
      <vc:Component Type="ZIP">1501</vc:Component>
    </Address>
    <Latitude>-26.097595</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-26.097595</Longitude>
    <MarkerSize>medium</MarkerSize>
    <Zoom>14</Zoom>
    <MarkerColour>red</MarkerColour>
    <MarkerName>H</MarkerName>
    <Type>hybrid</Type>

  </Place>
</ModelList>
```

when i try load my data to my database(through xml) i get this error:

*[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Place'. One of '{"http://www.onenetwork.com/Platform":Error, "http://www.onenetwork.com/Platform":Model}' is expected.]*

the xml file just assigns values to fields in the data base

Comment: Please add more text, info and research. Show us what you've done. We are here to help you learn, not free software support.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the namespaces. The XML just doesn't match the schema you are validating against.